# Image Capture OS X 10.6 won't read from iPhone

Tags: iphone, snow-leopard, image-capture

Image Capture on Snow Leopard says the "iPhone is locked with code", and asks to unlock it before importing images. The most weird thing is that it can import just fine using iPhoto and it syncs through iTunes. Seems it is a problem with Image Capture, any ideas?

If anyone could try to send the Image Capture.app to me to test with, that would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With ImageCapture closed, look in `~/Library/Preferences` for `com.apple.Image_Capture.plist` and `com.apple.ImageCaptureExtension2.plist` and move them to the Trash. Preferences files often become corrupt, and this is the first, easiest step.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following on OSX 10.6 and 10.7 *and it works*. **Being very quick** to press "trust" (on iPhones dialog 'trust this computer') might be a solution for you too. Please see the detailed description here:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/297828/254849

Erasing the plists (as described by @Emil and @Zo219, above) works for me, but *only* if I erase them each time I want to connect and import.

Comment: If you can give the same answer to several questions you should not give an answer but flag the question as a duplicate