# Trusting my computer with my iPhone no longer unlocks it for access (iPhone 5 w/iOS10, and Mac OSX 10.7.5)

Tags: iphone, macos, data-transfer, ios

Ever since I upgraded to iOS10 my computer doesn't recognize when my iPhone "trusts" my computer. My computer recognizes the device, but it's not allowed to access it.

In Image Capture: `Please unlock iPhone`

In iTunes: `iTunes could not connect to the iPhone because an invalid response was received from the device.`

In XCode: `Received an unexpected response from the device. Please check your setup and try again. (0xE8000013).`

**How do I get my computer to recognize my iPhone is unlocked and trusts the computer?**

I am using Mac OSX 10.7.5, and I have an iPhone 5 with iOS10. I refuse to upgrade my OS to fix this problem, because if upgrading my old iPhone hardware to new software was any indication, all it will do is slow it down. My computer is a 2011 MacBook Air.

Comment: I'd be prepared to stick my neck out & say that's your issue, current iOS trying to communicate with long-abandoned OS X. Your phone is using an iOS your Mac was never prepared for, & never considered or tested for compatibility.

Comment: What version of iTunes?

Comment: Just as an FYI, I found that older Macs performed better under El Capitan than 10.8 or 10.9. Your experience may differ. But I agree with Tetsujin, you're unlikely to be able to fix this in an unsupported OS.

Comment: @dr.nixon Hmm, that's good to know. I've just been skeptical because iOS 10 has slowed down my older phone, and many of the new features of the latest OSX updates aren't even available for the older machines (<2012). I also can't find good reviews for how these newer Mac OS's work on my old machine. I would be much less skeptical if I could read the review of a trailblazer with my conditions. I am also very short on drive space (<4GB free space, constantly have to delete things), and it's unclear exactly what net storage space I'll lose in the update.

Comment: A relative has this same problem: 2011 iMac on 10.7.5 cannot recognize an unlocked iPhone 5 on iOS 10.

Answer (score 2):

It appears the contents of

```
/var/db/lockdown
```

a folder on your mac, are corrupt.

First, unplug your iPhone or iPad.

Quit any apps that try to communicate with the iDevice e.g. Photos, Image Capture, iTunes, PhoneView, iMazing, iFunbox or Dropbox.

Delete the files within /var/db/lockdown/ (not the folder).

Plug your iDevice back in.

The “Trust this computer?” dialog box should appear. Tap *Trust* on your iDevice.

The operating system should create new .plist files in the lockdown folder. Try reopening one of the apps that had the error.

Comment: Interesting point. Would be great to know if that work for the OP...

Comment: It worked for me.  I deleted all the files in this folder and then I was able to trust the phone again.

Answer (score 1):

I found this simple bypass bug trick that works for me using iOS 10.3.3 on iPhone SE while connecting to Mac OS X Lion 10.7.5 on a vintage MacPro:

1. Do not connect iPhone yet
2. Quit Image Capture (or similar) if running
3. Unlock iPhone
4. Connect iPhone with USB
5. Click on "Trust" computer ***immediately** (within a second)*
6. Start Image Capture (or application of choice) - if not set to automatically start.

I also tried [@jasonology's method](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/295226/37797) but found I had to erase the plists each time to make it work.

PS: On OS X 10.9.4 / iPhone SE 12.3.1I needed to disable the passcode on the iphone beforehand as well, probably to be able to go through the process of ‘trust this computer’ fast enough.

Answer (score 1):

1. Plug your device into your Mac
2. Open finder and on the left sidebar under "locations" you should see your device
3. Click on it and a button will appear in the finder window that says "trust"
4. Click it and you will see the "trust" dialog open on your device
5. Tap trust on your device

- tested on macOS 11.1 and iOS 14.2

Answer (score 0):

As @Tetsujin mentions in the comments, compatibility issues between a brand new version of iOS and an old Mac OS one are likely to blame.

To be more precise, drivers required to communicate with iOS are packaged in iTunes, and Mac OS X 10.7 does not support anything higher than iTunes 12.3 (2015). Since iOS 10 was released, 3 new minor iTunes versions were released, all introducing new updates to these drivers...

Bottom line advice: if you cannot or do not wish to update macOS, don't update iOS neither. Don't forget Lion was released along with iOS 5!

Answer (score -3):

update macOS, don't update iOS neither. Don't forget Lion was released along with iOS 5!

Comment: I’m not sure why you’d want to not update iOS; maybe you could expand on this?