# Constant "please unlock iPhone" message in Photos 2.0

Tags: iphone, macos, photos.app, unlock, image-capture

I recently upgraded my Mac Pro from Yosemite to Sierra, and whenever I plug in my iPhone 6s, both iTunes and Photos will open as they should.  However within Photos (and Image Capture), I get a "please unlock iPhone" message.  When I unlock my iPhone, everything proceeds.  While I do not get the "unlock phone" nag from iPhoto, however, my photo library has been converted to use Photos.

As per discussions at the Apple forums, I've reset my iPhone's network settings.  This prompted a fresh "trust this computer" dialog on my iPhone, for which I clicked "trust".  Unfortunately, this had no effect on Photos or Image Capture, which are still asking me to unlock the iPhone.

How can I get Photos and Image Capture to recognize this iPhone and stop asking me to unlock it?

- macOS Sierra 10.12.3
- Photos 2.0
- iPhone 6s running iOS 10.2.1

Comment: You don't. It's to prevent unauthorised copying. You can't copy from a locked device. afaik, it's not Photos, it's the phone, since iOS 10, as the same happens on El Capitan now.

Comment: @Tetsujin, is this documented someplace?  Why require unlocking to dump photos, yet a locked phone dumps everything else into iTunes with no problem.  Makes no sense.  However, this seems to be the case.

Comment: I've no idea. It's just been that way since iOS 10.

Answer (score -1):

Being very quick to press "trust" (on iPhones dialog 'trust this computer') might be a solution. Please see the detailed description here:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/297828/254849

Comment: My iPhone is already set to "trust" my computer, and seriously what does "being very quick" have to do with anything?  AFAIK, this whole issue affects everyone and you now have to manually unlock the iPhone to allow Photos to access it.

Comment: [Quoting the policy of SE, my original comment fits the definition exactly](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment):  *"You should submit a comment if you want to: **Request clarification from the author**; Leave **constructive criticism** that guides the author in improving the post; **Add relevant but minor or transient information** to a post;"*